# detection out of bounds screen

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I need some image to appear randomly on screen, then start moving, and detection of ended moving. How do I get this? I mean detection ended moving UIView?

These my code:

```
imageNames = @[@"some_array_picture"];

    image = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
        [image addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    leftX = arc4random_uniform(6) + 10;
    leftY = arc4random()%500;
    rightX = arc4random_uniform(220) + 20;
    rightY = arc4random()%500;
    tempX = rightX;
    tempY = rightY;

    animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rightX, rightY, 75, 57.5)];
    animationImageView.animationImages = image;
    animationImageView.animationDuration = 1;

    [self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:animationImageView];
    [animationImageView startAnimating];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:10.0f];
    animationImageView.frame = CGRectMake(leftY, leftY, animationImageView.frame.size.width, animationImageView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Because I need to rotate horizontally at the end of motion, have this code:

```
animationImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(animationImageView.transform, -1.0, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your 'title' you ask for detecting when a view is outside the screens bounds, but in you question you ask for detection of the end of the animation.

For the latter, I would recommend using `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`. It calls the completion-block, when the animation is finished.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0
     animations:^{ animationImageView.frame = CGRectMake(leftY, leftY, animationImageView.frame.size.width, animationImageView.frame.size.height); }
     completion:^(BOOL finished){ animationImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(animationImageView.transform, -1.0, 1.0);
}];
```

Apple recommends using the block-based animation in the developer documentation for UIView:

*There are two different ways to initiate animations:*

- *In iOS 4 and later, use the block-based animation methods. (Recommended)*
- *Use the begin/commit animation methods.*

Comment: no smooth animation here, in my example animationImageView moving smooth((

Comment: mb should use collision detected on screen bounds?

Answer (score -1):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10
                         animations:^{
                             animationImageView.frame = CGRectMake(leftY, leftY, animationImageView.frame.size.width, animationImageView.frame.size.height);

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

// do something here : it is called at the end of the animation
}];
```